# MySQL - Query for obtaining record when 2 columns match 2 or more values at the same time

Tags: mysql, query

I have this database that I got from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923469/modeling-product-variants) that manages products and its variants:

```
+---------------+     +---------------+
| PRODUCTS      |-----< PRODUCT_SKUS  |
+---------------+     +---------------+
| #product_id   |     | #product_id   |
|  product_name |     | #sku_id       |
+---------------+     |  sku          |
        |             |  price        |
        |             +---------------+
        |                     |
+-------^-------+      +------^------+
| OPTIONS       |------< SKU_VALUES  |
+---------------+      +-------------+
| #product_id   |      | #product_id |
| #option_id    |      | #sku_id     |
|  option_name  |      | #option_id  |
+---------------+      |  value_id   |
        |              +------v------+
+-------^-------+             |
| OPTION_VALUES |-------------+
+---------------+
| #product_id   |
| #option_id    |
| #value_id     |
|  value_name   |
+---------------+
```

The problem is that I don't know how would I get the SKU at the moment that a user selects the options of the product he wants:

```
SKU_VALUES
==========
product_id sku_id option_id value_id
---------- ------ --------- --------
1          1      1         1        (W1SSCW; Size; Small)
1          1      2         1        (W1SSCW; Color; White)
1          2      1         1        (W1SSCB; Size; Small)
1          2      2         2        (W1SSCB; Color; Black)
```

Let's suppose that the user selects the product with ID 1 and the options size-small and color-black, how am I able to get the `sku_id` (in this case I would want value 2 from `sku_id`) in order to get the price that's inside the `PRODUCT_SKUS` table, I CANNOT write the following because it obviously doesn't make sense:

```
SELECT sku_id FROM SKU_VALUES 
WHERE (SKU_VALUES.option_id = 1 AND SKU_VALUES.value_id = 1) 
AND (SKU_VALUES.option_id = 2 AND SKU_VALUES.value_id = 2)
```

NOTE that it seems that I would need to append the same number of conditions (or whatever I need) as the number of options that are available from a product, in this case there are just 2 rows because the product has 2 options (size and color), but the product may have "n" options.

Comment: Yes tht is right, but you must have a form app or what ever you use as gui, where you can choose those options, and when you select your choice you build the query with all the options you got.

Comment: @nbk Yes, I know that I’ll need the UI but, how will I get the product variation that the user selects?, and I’m referring to a query not at the UI.

Comment: for that you should check, how it is done in php,python,, c# vb net asp net core 3.0 you see where i am getting at, first select a language or system and then start from there with the basics, you jump in the middle and want what? you have to invest time and lean

Comment: But I don’t want help with logic in the back end, I just want help writing the raw sql query.

Comment: now you lost me, so you have a gui where you select options and then you wqant to call 1 compltely written query for all options available.

Comment: @nbk No, be sure to read the part where I mention that I need the field sku_id when the user finishes selecting the product variation he wants.